# Issues resizing UITableView header with animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm tying to animate my table view's header height to 0 its. The current code I am using is:

```
    var newRect = headerView.frame
    newRect.size.height = 0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6) {
        self.headerView.frame = newRect
    }
```

`headerView` is a custom UIView and used like so:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


        return headerView

    }
```

When I run the code it seems to animate the `headerView`'s height to just half its size and not 0. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use `heightForHeaderInSection` and `UITableView` reload system. Bellow, there  is an example of how to do it. It's a dummy example (when use presses a cell, it makes the section header (dis)appear.

```
var displayExpandedHeader = true
let expandedHeight = CGFloat(50)
let colapsedHeight = CGFloat(0)
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return headerView
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    displayExpandedHeader = !displayExpandedHeader
    tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section), withRowAnimation: (!displayExpandedHeader) ? .Top : .Bottom)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return (displayExpandedHeader) ? expandedHeight : colapsedHeight
}
```